# POSTMAN - get url query param - url encoding in datetime with timezone + sign issue

Tags: express, postman, web-api-testing

**Can anybody show me how to encode in postman?**

I am using postman for rest api testing.

**Get** request- `/xyz/abc?start=2001-05-04T00:00:00+5:30`

When I am testing this request in postman, I am getting query parameters start in backend like this `2001-05-04T00:00:00 5:30`

Here `+` is replaced with `space`

Note: My backend api is in express.js

I know something has to be done in query param like I need to encode url but I couldn't find any way to encode query param in postman.

Comment: @Quentin I know we need to encode parameter but I wants to know how to do in postman? Please read my last sentence in question? Can you please reopen it?

Comment: There is not a specific way available to encode query parameters when you found special characters then you should convert in Unicode characters and then pass in query string.

Comment: In your case, links should /xyz/abc?start?start=2001-05-04T00:00:00%2B5:30